# how to cp (copy) files in TFS like you can in SVN

Tags: svn, tfs, visual-studio-2013

In TFS I have a folder with lots of sub-folders that I want to copy to into another project that lives in the same TFS repository. Ideally I'd like the new copy of the files to still be associated w/ the version history of the files that they were copied from. In SVN I would use the copy command in order to do this, and the new copy of the files would still be connected to the version history of the old files. How can I do this in TFS?

For example, I have a folder /project 1/assets/ that I want to copy to folder /project 2/assets/. /project 2/assets/ already exists and has other things inside it. I need to "copy" everything inside /project1/assets/ to /project 2/assets/, and retain the link between the new copy and the old copy.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS this is called a Branch. You can see the documentation on MSDN for [Branching files and Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx) to get a good feel for how this works.

Under the covers TFS minimised the disk space used by using pointers until you edit a file. If you view history on one of the new 'branched' files you will see a single "branched from" entry that has a tree designator. Click the tree designator to see the history inline from the other branches.

You can even visualise how the new copy is related to its parents and siblings so that you can keep it in sync and push fixes across the structure.

Works pretty well... make sure that you have a minimalist strategy.